# user adjustable panels pygtk

Tags: pygtk, glade

How to create user adjustable panels in PyGTK using GLADE? I have 2 panels in my window. Both the panels are packed horizontally but they remain exactly half of the window. And I require them to be user adjustable (varying width with same height). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [GtkPaned](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkPaned.html) widget, instead of GtkBox.

This widgets allows only two childrens and haves a separator/handler that allows the user to manually adjust the children's areas. It pretty much fits the description of your problem.